# How to access to k8s Ingress from inside the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have stateful serviceA and I need to access using sticky session. To implement the sticky session I'm using nginx ingress with the annotations

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity-mode: "persistent"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
```

When I call the serviceA from outside the cluster, everything is fine.

Now the problem is that I need serviceB that is inside k8s to access to serviceA and still benefit of the sticky session, so the traffic needs to be `serviceB -> Ingress -> serviceA`

I could implement that, just using the public hostname of Ingress, but I'd like to avoid to have the traffic to go out of the cluster and then back again. So using the public host the traffic would be `serviceB -> NAT -> Public LoadBalancer Ingress -> Logical Ingress -> serviceA`

So I was wondering if there is the possibility for serviceB to access to Ingress directly so that the traffic would be `serviceB -> Logical Ingress -> serviceA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution for that would to set a new service inside your cluster and configure it to selects the ingress controller pod.

Let's say we would call this service `ingress-internal-service` and you can easily create that with command:

```sh
➜  ~ k expose deployment -n kube-system ingress-nginx-controller --name ingress-internal-service --port 80

service/ingress-internal-service exposed
```

As you can see my service now has one endpoint that matches my `ingress-controller-pod`:

```sh
#POD 
kube-system   ingress-nginx-controller-558664778f-dn2cl   1/1     Running     24h     172.17.0.7

#SERVICE
Name:              ingress-internal-service
-----
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.111.197.14
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.7:80
```

And here is a test I made with curl (`myapp.com` is my ingress host)

```sh
[root@cent /]#  curl -H "Host: myapp.com" http://10.111.197.14  
{
  "path": "/",
  "headers": {
    "host": "myapp.com",
    "x-request-id": "ec03f71b9772921c4b07112297ee2e43",
    "x-real-ip": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-for": "172.17.0.1",
    "x-forwarded-host": "myapp.com",
    "x-forwarded-port": "80",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-scheme": "http",
    "user-agent": "curl/7.29.0",
    "accept": "*/*"
  },
  "method": "GET",
  "body": "",
  "fresh": false,
  "hostname": "myapp.com",
  "ip": "172.17.0.1",
  "ips": [
    "172.17.0.1"
```

This is pretty similar to the [node-port-bare-metal](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/#over-a-nodeport-service) way of exposing nginx controller with the difference that we are just using the ClusterIp instead.

PS. If you are using cloud environment you may want o check/consider using [Using an internal TCP/UDP load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balancing).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to do something like this but I wasn't sure how to expose the ingress as service, I didn't think to refer is as deployment